# Which of the following is correct?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p\geq 23$ be a prime number such that the decimal expression (base $10$ ) of $\frac{1}{p}$ is periodic with period $p-1$ (that is ,$\frac{1}{v}=0.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_{p-1}}$) with $a_i\in \{0,1\dots 9\}$ for all $t$ and for any $m$, $1\leq m<p-1$, $\frac{1}{p}\neq 0.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_m}$).

Let $(\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$ denote the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$. Then which of the following is correct?

- The order of $10\in (\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$ is a proper divisor of $(p-1)$.
- The order of $10\in (\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$ is $\frac{(v-1)}{2}$.
- The order of $10\in (\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$ is a generator of the group $(\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$
- The group $(\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}})^*$ is cyclic but not generated by the element $10$.

How to start this problem? Really, I don't have any idea.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that saying $\frac{1}{p}$ has decimal period $p-1$ is the same as saying that the minimal positive integer $x$ for which $\frac{10^x}{p}$ has the same decimal part as $\frac{1}{p}$ is $x=p-1$. Now, this is equivalent to saying:
$$\frac{10^x}{p}-\frac{1}{p} \in \mathbb{Z} \iff 10^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
So, $p-1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $10^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. In other words, $10$ has order $p-1$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$. Since the group has order $p-1$, we can see that $10$ is the generator of the group.

Thus, option (c) is right. You can see that (c) immediately implies (d) is incorrect. Moreover, as the order of $10$ is $p-1$, (a) and (b) are incorrect. Hence, (c) is the only correct answer.